# PL/SQL Trigger not evaluating IF condition as expected

Tags: oracle, plsql, eventtrigger

I'm having some hard time trying to make this small piece of pl/sql work!
If someone could figure out what is actually blocking?
the purpose of the script is to audit DDL `alter user` actions causing an account to expire or lock.

I tried debugging it with `dbms_output.put_line`, and it seems that its not evaluating the `IF (user_status_ = 16 AND l_action = 'LOCK')` to TRUE. most likely to be an issue with the variable `l_action` cause when i remove it, it does log something in the table when the cond user_status_ = 16 is met.

however if i print out l_action with `dbms_output.put_line('action: ' || l_action);` it shows me the correct value. see below

```
Trigger created.

SQL>
SQL>
SQL> alter user PERFSTAT account lock;
action: LOCK
```

here's is my trigger :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
TRIGGER trg_lock_track AFTER ALTER ON DATABASE
WHEN (ora_dict_obj_type = 'USER')
DECLARE
  session_id VARCHAR2(50);
  ip_addr    VARCHAR2(50);
  hostname   VARCHAR2(50);
  auth_type  VARCHAR2(50);
  l_session_user  VARCHAR2(50);
  l_module  VARCHAR2(100);
  l_osuser  VARCHAR2(50);
  user_name_ VARCHAR2(50);
  user_status_ NUMBER;  
  user_datelock_ DATE;  
  user_dateexp_ DATE;
  l_action VARCHAR2(50);
  sql_text ora_name_list_t;
  v_stmt VARCHAR2(2000);
  n PLS_INTEGER;

BEGIN 
  IF (ora_dict_obj_name != 'SYS' AND ora_dict_obj_name != 'SYSTEM') THEN
    SELECT sys_context('USERENV', 'SESSIONID'), 
           sys_context('USERENV', 'IP_ADDRESS'), 
           sys_context('USERENV', 'HOST'), 
           sys_context('USERENV', 'MODULE'), 
           sys_context('USERENV', 'OS_USER'), 
           sys_context('USERENV', 'AUTHENTICATION_TYPE'), 
           sys_context('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER')
    INTO session_id, ip_addr, hostname, l_module, l_osuser, auth_type, l_session_user
    FROM dual;

    SELECT NAME, ASTATUS, LTIME , EXPTIME
    INTO user_name_, user_status_, user_datelock_, user_dateexp_  
    FROM user$ 
    WHERE NAME = ora_dict_obj_name;

    n := ora_sql_txt(sql_text);
    FOR i IN 1..n LOOP
      v_stmt := v_stmt || sql_text(i);
    END LOOP;

    SELECT UPPER(SUBSTR(v_stmt, INSTR(v_stmt,' ',-1) + 1))
    INTO l_action
    FROM DUAL;

    IF (user_status_ = 16 AND l_action = 'LOCK') THEN 
      INSERT INTO sys.event_table VALUES 
      (sysdate, session_id, ip_addr, hostname, l_module, l_osuser, auth_type, ora_sysevent, ora_login_user, ora_database_name, 
      ora_dict_obj_name, ora_dict_obj_type, l_action);

    ELSIF (user_status_ = 16 AND l_action = 'EXPIRE') THEN
      INSERT INTO sys.event_table VALUES 
      (sysdate, session_id, ip_addr, hostname, l_module, l_osuser, auth_type, ora_sysevent, ora_login_user, ora_database_name, 
      ora_dict_obj_name, ora_dict_obj_type, l_action);  
    END IF;

  END IF;
END;
/
```

the table sys.event_table :

```
create table event_table
(
event_datetime  date,
session_id VARCHAR2(30),
ip_addr VARCHAR2(30),
hostname VARCHAR2(100),
l_module VARCHAR2(100),
l_osuser VARCHAR2(30),
auth_type VARCHAR2(30),
l_ora_sysevent varchar2(20),
l_ora_login_user varchar2(30),
l_ora_database_name varchar2(50),
l_ora_dict_obj_name varchar2(30),
l_ora_dict_obj_type varchar2(20),
action varchar2(20)
)
/
```

i would appreciate any help in this matter.

Comment: maybe, you can try `upper(l_action) = 'LOCK'`

Comment: or trim(upper(l_action)) = 'LOCK'

Comment: thanks. tried it still not good.

`SQL> alter user PERFSTAT account lock;
action: LOCK

User altered.

SQL>
SQL>
SQL> select * from sys.event_table;

no rows selected`

Comment: not working neither with `trim(upper(l_action)) = 'LOCK'`.

`SQL> alter user PERFSTAT account unlock;
action: UNLOCK

User altered.

SQL> alter user PERFSTAT account lock;
action: LOCK

User altered.

SQL> select * from sys.event_table;

no rows selected`

Comment: Are you sure the trigger is compiling correctly and that you get no exception when it runs?

Comment: Yes im sure, all is fine.

```
SQL> alter trigger sys.trg_lock_track compile;

Trigger altered.

SQL> show errors
No errors.
```

Comment: well, are you sure about the equality : `user_status_ = 16` ?

Comment: yes, its fine...
added to the code `dbms_output.put_line('user_status: ' || user_status_);`

Trigger created.

SQL> set serverout on
SQL> alter user PERFSTAT account lock;
action: LOCK
user_status: 16

User altered.

Comment: as part of experiment could you please try addding the ELSE cases for the both IF statements and try inserting respective results in the table (and separately outputting anything via dbms_output) this would help making sure the IF statement is the culprit

Comment: added the else. it works.

`
Trigger created.

SQL>
SQL>
SQL> alter user PERFSTAT account unlock;
action: UNLOCK
user_status: 24

User altered.

SQL> alter user PERFSTAT account lock;
action: LOCK
user_status: 16

User altered.

SQL>
SQL>
SQL> set line 250
SQL> set pages 1000
SQL> select * from sys.event_table;
SQL> select count(1) from sys.event_table;

  COUNT(1)
----------
         2
`

Comment: Performance of your trigger will be better if you don't use "select ... into... from dual". There's no need for that construct; just assign the values to the variables directly:

Comment: e.g. session_id := sys_context('USERENV', 'SESSIONID');

Comment: With else, since you're doing the insert you can check all ascii characters in l_action, to see where's the problem.

Comment: @pmdba, well noted . thanks

Comment: @WoAiNii, i did check. no non-ascii character to be found in the action col. see below
`SQL> SELECT *
  FROM event_table
 WHERE ACTION != asciistr(ACTION);        2    3

no rows selected`

Comment: what is the output of the below select * from event_table where INSTR(action,' LOCK') > 0;

Comment: @psaraj12 

`SQL> select * from event_table where INSTR(action,' LOCK') > 0;

no rows selected`

i think its a trailing character or whitespace. but im not sure how to remove it.
`SQL> SELECT length(ACTION) , length('LOCK') from event_table;

LENGTH(ACTION) LENGTH('LOCK')
-------------- --------------
             7              4
             5              4
`

Comment: maybe like this its clearer:

`SQL> SELECT length(ACTION) from event_table where action like 'LOCK%';

LENGTH(ACTION)
--------------
             5

SQL> SELECT length('LOCK') from dual;

LENGTH('LOCK')
--------------
             4`

i tried trim, rtrim, tochar but im not able to figure out what the trailing character.

Comment: Have you tried also initializing v_stmt with empty string? Or using regexp_replace(l_action, '[^A-Z]', '') = 'LOCK' ?

Comment: @WoAiNii, i understand that v_stmt is local to the for loop and goes out of scope once the for loop ends.
what one would expect is to have an outer variable v_stmt initialize to empty string and which would be fed by the for loop v_stmt.
once the loop ends the outer v_stmt would come again in scope.
but if this is the case, how do you explain my dbms_output.put_line can print out the v_stmt after the end of the forloop without having v_stmt being declared to
an empty string?
just to understand the logic?
i will try your regex and let you know. thanks

Comment: @AtishDharvesh That's why I'm asking, I'm missing that part too, you declare v_stmt VARCHAR2(2000), without initializing it (e.g.:= '';) and in the loop concatenate it, so I would expect an error, but I could just missing something.

Comment: @WoAiNii, the regex works in some situations but not in others.

    alter user PERFSTAT account lock; -> works 
    alter user PERFSTAT account lock<one or more space>; -> doesn't work 
    alter user PERFSTAT account lock<line break>(/ or ;) -> works.
    alter user PERFSTAT account lock<line break><one or more space>/ -> works
    alter user PERFSTAT account lock<line break><one or more space>; -> doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i finally found a way around.took advantage of the oracle internal syntactical error checking and used INSTR and SUBSTR in a more appropriate way to overcome few issues when using the regex.
it now takes into account nth space, line break or a mix of both in the alter command.

`SUBSTR(UPPER(v_stmt),(INSTR(RTRIM(UPPER(v_stmt)),' LOCK') +1),4)`

of course you should ensure its not evaluating to 1 (meaning word not found) before using the outcome.

Many thanks to you all for your constructive comments which help me a lot in getting closer to the solution.